# Trying to connect from PHP 7.1.3 to MYSQL 5.7.31 on Windows 10

Tags: php, windows, mysql-connector

We have recently up graded to PHP 7 from 5 and have encountered a connection error from our PHP to MySQL. We have tried both PDO and mysqli, which works on a dev machine with the only obvious difference being that MySQL is 5.6.34.0 and not 5.7.31, but this fails to connect with a "Connection failed: could not find driver"

Within the php.ini file the following are uncommented:

```
extension=mysqli
extension=pdo_mysql
```

And have tried setting the extension_dir to the absolute path as well as the relative path.

When any change to the config has been made Apache has been restarted.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Did you know that PHP 7.1 is no longer supported? Please, consider upgrading soon

Comment: For some reason you are missing mysqlnd. Although your question is not very clear

Comment: Downloaded a later version of PHP, 8.0.0rc1  &configured Apache...

```
# Update the PHP directory path as per your setup.
PHPIniDir "C:/localserver/php-8.0.0rc1"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
LoadModule php8_module "C:/localserver/php-8.0.0rc1/php8apache2_4.dll"
```

but Apache is failing to start

```
The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 541 of C:/localserver/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `php8_module' in file C:/localserver/php-8.0.0rc1/php8apache2_4.dll: No error     .
```

Comment: PHP 8.0 hasn't been released yet. While you can use it for testing I would recommend to stick with PHP 7.4 for time being. What does it mean apache fails to start. What error does it give?

Comment: OK downloaded 7.4.11 and configured. Apache has started and the test.php file loads.

On the info screen there is no "mysqli" section

Comment: PHP install directory was not in the path. Once this had been added mysqli and pdo_mysql appear in the test.php screen